# Cast from 'String' to unrelated type 'LocationModel' always fails warning

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, typeerror, nspredicate

In an NSArray, I need to filter all elements containing a searchKey (eg 39013). For now, I can print and see the values on Xcode but I want them on my device. I have two arrays. 
First one is:

```
var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
```

and the filtered one is

```
var filteredData:[String] = []
```

I print the filteredData and everything is as I wanted. Here is the problem I made a mistake on **viewController** while printing the lines.

```
if resultSearchController.isActive {

     let item: LocationModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! LocationModel
```

I need to change `.. = feedItems` to `.. = filteredData` But when I change, since the `filteredData` is a String Array (Not an NSarray) I get an error:

> Cast from 'String' to unrelated type 'LocationModel' always fails

Can you help me to fix the last problem? Thank you so much!!

Following is the Code:

Here is the object:

```
import UIKit
class LocationModel: NSObject {
    //properties
     var DesenNo: String?
     var Dolar: String?
     var Zemin: String?
     var En: String?
     var Euro: String?
     var Renk: String?
}
```

Comment: Start by replacing your use of `NSArray` with a proper Swift array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 3+ try to avoid (NS)Stuff like `NSArray`. Prefers the Swift version when available.

You declared:

```
var filteredData:[String] = []
```

So `filteredData` will be an array of `String`, of ONLY `String` objects.

Then you do

```
let item: LocationModel = filteredData[indexPath.row] as! LocationModel
```

But you said previously that `filteredData` will be an array of String objects. So `filteredData[indexPath.row]` should be a `String` object. But you are trying to force cast it into a `LocationModel` object. The compiler is saying: That's not happening, I can't convert a `String` object into a `LocationModel` object.

With `NSArray`, objects inside are of type `Any`. If you declare `filteredData` as `NSArray` but put inside `LocationModel` objects:

```
let item: LocationModel = filteredDataAsNSArray[indexPath.row] as! LocationModel
```

That will crash, no doubt about it.

There are still some issues, I think you want ta filteredData being of `LocationModel` objects

Do this:

```
var filteredData:[LocationModel] = []()
var feedItems:[LocationModel] = []()
```

The filtering: You want to filter on each values of your `LocationModel` so the predicate format should be:

```
(SELF.DesenNo CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (SELF.Dolar CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (SELF.Zemin CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (SELF.En CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (SELF.Euro CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (SELF.Renk CONTAINS[c] %@)
```

You could also use a Swift filter in pseudo code (not tested):

```
let textToSearch = searchController.searchBar.text
filteredData = feedItems.filter({$0.DesenNo.lowercased().contains(textToSearch.lowercased()) || $0.DesenNo.lowercased().contains(textToSearch.lowercased()) || ...})
```

Also in `tableView(_ tableView:, cellForRowAt:)` you do the same thing again and again, that could should be factorized and for better clarity put into the `MyTableCell` code.
This way you could do something like `cell.updateWith(item:item)` and it will be clearer.

Edit: 
Last recommendation: Please rename your var starting with a lowercase (`DesenNo` => `desenNo`, etc.).

Comment: I am thankful for your time and response that was really helpful for me. But there is a little problem. `let filterArray = array.map {($0 as! LocationModel).DesenNo}
            filteredData = filterArray` on this line i am having error : **Cannot assign value of type '[String?]' to type '[LocationModel]'**

Comment: You are missing the part `caseInsensitiveCompare()` you need to compare `DesenNo` with the text you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the help man! This solved my 1 problem which i couldn't solve for a month! I appreciate you!!!

Comment: i didn't get the main idea of **caseInsensitiveCompare**. And little question: how can i do this live search? i mean when i put 40027, this function return every value which starts with 40027(for instance 40027-60)

Comment: Sorry, by bad: `$0.lowercased().contains(textToSearch.lowercased())` instead (or a quick search in SO about finding if substring is in string case insenstive should give you the correct wording)

Comment: And this time my bad. Couldn't understand where to put this. do you want me to change this code instead of caseInsensitiveCompare? Can you please explain more detailly?

Comment: I tried this but get the error **Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Bool' and '_'** Not sure but i think the problem is with **contains**